# In WSL version 2, where could I find the Windows folders?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I recently installed WSL version 2 according to [the instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install). Everything work greatly. But I notice that the folder `/mnt/c` is not available any more.

I understand the new WSL using `vhdx` as file system which gives us better FS performance, but I could not find a way to access files in Windows.

I also tried to check the `wsl --help` but I could not find anything helpful.

Any suggestions?

---

After read more, I notice that WSL 2 is actually an optimized VM on Windows 10, which means the running WSL 2 has no idea about where it self. Seems there should be a way to pass some Windows folders while launch it. Haven't figured out how.....

Answer (score 2):

By default, the command prompt in WSL is located at `C:\Users\username`. WSL considers this `/home/user` but you can can reference any directory on your Windows machine by starting at the root directory with `/../../`.

Here is an example command: `find "/../../mnt/c/anyFolder/subfolder" -name "test" -type d`